# Recording and downloading IRF outputs in VAR Models (Python)

Tags: python, vector-auto-regression

I have a query about Vector Autoregression model estimation in Python.

I estimated a simple VAR model and generated the Impulse Response Function from shocking one of the variables. (Code snippets provided below for reference)

When I generate impulse responses, I know how to create visual graphs of the response functions. My question is how do I record this data in a .csv/.txt/.xlsx file or any other downloadable file form? Thanks very much.

```
#VAR CODES & RESULTS 

model = VAR(data)
results = model.fit(2)
results.summary() 

#Impulse Response Function (IRF)

irf = results.irf(10)
irf.plot(orth=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but you can get the values with the following:

```py
print(irf.irfs)
print(irf.cum_effects)
```

You can then turn the arrays into a DataFrame and use the to_csv functionality in pandas:

```py
df.to_csv('your_csv.csv')
```